# comparing time without using queries

Tags: datetime, vb6

how to compare time without using queries ?
this is for knowing the conflict
public class TimeNo is for converting time to long
also theres an error in the code it says byref argument type mismatch error

```
Function getConflict() As Boolean
Me.lstSchedules.ListItems.clear
Dim currentStartTime, currentEndTime, startTime, endTime As Date
Set rs = Nothing

currentStartTime = Me.cboTime.Text
currrentendtime = Me.cboEnd.Text
With rs
    .CursorLocation = adUseClient
    .Open "select * from tblSecSched where Sections = '" & Me.cboSection.Text & "' and [Day] = '" & Me.cboDay.Text & "' and SchoolLevel = '" & Me.cboSchoolLevel.Text & "' and YearLevel = '" & Me.cboYearLevel.Text & "' and SchoolYear = '" & sH & "'", cs, 1, 2

    If .RecordCount > 0 Then
        getConflict = False
       Do While Not .EOF
            startTime = CDate(!TimeIn)
            endTime = CDate(!TimeOut)
            If ((TimeNo(startTime) < TimeNo(currentStartTime)) And (TimeNo(endTime) > TimeNo(currentStartTime))) Or ((TimeNo(startTime) < TimeNo(currentEndTime)) And (TimeNo(endTime) > TimeNo(currentEndTime))) Then
                MsgBox "Schedule Conflict", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
                Me.lstSchedules.ListItems.clear
                With Me.lstSchedules.ListItems.Add(, , !SchoolLevel)
                    .SubItems(1) = rs!YearLevel
                    .SubItems(2) = rs!Sections
                    .SubItems(3) = rs!Subject
                    .SubItems(4) = rs!TimeIn
                    .SubItems(5) = rs!TimeOut
                    .SubItems(6) = sH
                End With
            End If
            .MoveNext
        Loop
    Else
        getConflict = True
    End If
End With
End Function

Public Function TimeNo(Time As String) As Long
TimeNo = CLng(Replace(Format(Time, "hhnnss"), ":", ""))
End Function
```

Comment: Your Dim statement is incorrect. Only endTime is a Date, currentStartTime, currentEndTime, and startTime are all Variants. Try dimming only 1 variable per line. Also you're passing a Date to a function that expects a string.

Comment: thanks it worked .. but is my time checking for conflict is right ??

Comment: I don't know what the values of your time variables are. I would probably use the DateDiff function and look for overlap, but your function seems to work the way you want so just plug in some times you know do not conflict, and some times you know do conflict.

Comment: Variables of the Date data type can be compared directly -- why do you have a function that converts to Long?

Comment: how to compare directly the date data type ? im still not well rounded on comparing date data type ... so i just convert it to long ... please teach me the method to directly compare date data type ...

Comment: jac 14 i plugged some data that is conflict to other and it worked .. but i still dont know if that method is accurate